# How to fix log4j yaml config issue "main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender..."

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I have a config to log4j2 yaml config in spring boot app (version-2.1.1). It throws some exception like "main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration has multiple incompatible Appenders pointing to the same resource '../logs/app.log'"

Config File

```
Configutation:
  name: Default

  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "logs"

  Appenders:

    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ../${log-path}/app.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

    RollingFile:
        name: RollingFile_Appender
        fileName: ../${log-path}/app.log
        filePattern: "../${log-path}/log/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz"
        PatternLayout:
          pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
        Policies:
          SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
            size: 5000 KB
        DefaultRollOverStrategy:
          max: 30

  Loggers:

      Root:
        level: error
        AppenderRef:
            ref: Console_Appender

      Logger:
          name: com.app
          level: error
          AppenderRef:
              ref: Console_Appender
              level: info
              ref: File_Appender
              level: error
              ref: RollingFile_Appender
              level: debug
```

Below mention, Exception throws while app deploying

````
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.narrow(AbstractManager.java:162)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
   at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:135)
   at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:102)
   at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:79)
   at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
   at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:194)
   at com.app.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:14)

2019-01-14 02:23:32,021 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2019-01-14 02:23:32,031 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile_Appender" for logger config "com.app"
2019-01-14 02:23:32,676 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration has multiple incompatible Appenders pointing to the same resource '../logs/app.log'
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.narrow(AbstractManager.java:162)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:188)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:145)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:61)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:123)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
   at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.reinitialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:193)
   at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:75)
   at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
   at org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.initialize(Log4J2LoggingSystem.java:147)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:293)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:266)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:229)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:202)
   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
   at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
   at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
   at com.app.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:14)

2019-01-14 02:23:32,685 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2019-01-14 02:23:32,693 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "RollingFile_Appender" for logger config "com.app"```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the stack trace is very clear:
`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration has multiple incompatible Appenders pointing to the same resource '../logs/app.log'`

Both of your appenders are using the same file and looks like that log4j does not support it.

You need to change the YAML file to use different files. For example:

```
File:
    name: File_Appender
    fileName: ../${log-path}/file.log
    PatternLayout:
    pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"

RollingFile:
    name: RollingFile_Appender
    fileName: ../${log-path}/app.log
    filePattern: "../${log-path}/log/app.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.gz"
    PatternLayout:
      pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
    Policies:
      SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        size: 5000 KB
    DefaultRollOverStrategy:
      max: 30
```